# How to insert zeros into a string?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, toad

I have a string, for example X1. I need to create a new string by inserting zeros into it. To be more specific:

```
for X1 the new string will be X0001;
for X10 the new string will be X0010;
for X100 the new string will be X0100;
for X1000 the new string will be X1000.


The length of the new string is 5.
```

I have tried to do this:

```
select substr('X1', 1, 1) || '000' || substr('X1', 2) from dual;
```

But this solves only the first case and in returning X0001.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `LPAD` with `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT
    col,
    SUBSTR(col, 1, 1) || LPAD(SUBSTR(col, 2), 4, '0') AS col_padded
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: @Nick It's funny you feel that way, because I usually think this about Gordon Linoff (who regularly beats me on this site).

Comment: Evidently they need a response speed ladder the same way as they have a reputation ladder :-)

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 I could swear I've opened newly posted questions and there was already a Gordon answer when it loaded `:-P`

Comment: Yes, Gordon gives answer within fraction of second with quality. Kudos to both of you..

Answer (score 0):

Does X always come before the number? There are no numbers in X?

If yes to both, the following will work for you:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(REGEXP_REPLACE(`example`, '[^a-z]', ""),REGEXP_REPLACE(LPAD(`example`,5,0), '[^0-9]+', ""))
FROM `test`
```

What we're doing here is, concatenation of the string field (example) with a version that contains just the text, then, we're adding a version that contains just the number, left padded for 5 characters, added a 0 for anything under 5.

The first regexp removes anything not a character, the latter anything not a number, to allow you to pad and piece back together.

If X contains anything other than letters you'll need to adjust the first regexp (good details can be found [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)) - if it contains any integers then this will not work.

It's a sort of "quick and dirty" fix, but, does meet the criteria you've set out as far as I understand them = )

[edit]
Ahh, looks like I was beaten to it by the above, that works perfectly fine, the difference my code will work for any given length of X, if that's needed.